# EE Admin Typekit error?

Tags: ee2

In our backoffice, I'm seeing this, which, of course, renders our Admin area almost unusable:

[image]

Has anyone seen this or know how to fix it? I can't find **ANY** instances of `jqv4zpf` or even `cycle.min` **ANYWHERE** on my system.

Apparently this only happened recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have face the same issue. The error occurs in EE versions lower then EE 2.2. Actual error is not of typkit or something but the accessory named "ExpressionEngine Info". I uninstalled this accessory and it works.

Comment: Wow, wonder why it is happening and what made it start happening.

Comment: The problem was API. If you know, Elislab change the site URLs after launch of EE3. That might affect the API urls. I then copied EE2.5 "ExpressionEngine Info" accessory and it works. :)